# link library to all targets in cmake project

Tags: cmake

Consider a project which consists of a library and a set of executable that use that library.  A straightforward approach is to `add_library()`, followed by a sequence of `add_executable()` `target_link_libraries()` pairs.

This is a lot of boilerplate coding.  It would be nice to able to do something like `set(PROJECT_LINK_LIBS, lib1 ...)`, and have CMake remove the extra boilerplate.

Thinking on this more, I realize I would like a `link_libraries` function that behaves similarly to `include_directories`. I would argue that this:

1. Would be useful in a lot of cases.
2. Would lead to dryer CMakeLists.
3. Would encourage better code organizations -- there would be a natural incentive to organize the folders, code, and executables in such a way that all executables have the same dependancies -- certainly a clean practice.

Is there anything like this?

Comment: There is nothing builtin that removes this. However you can develop your own cmake macros and functions to remove some of the boilerplate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmake: add library to all targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292879/cmake-add-library-to-all-targets)

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50295894/129550 the requested `link_libraries(example example2)` function is actually now a part of cmake.

Answer (score 2):

**This answer might be obsolete**:
Check the new set of variables [`CMAKE_<LANG>_STANDARD_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_STANDARD_LIBRARIES.html)

*Original Answer:*
It appears that now a [`CMAKE_STANDARD_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_STANDARD_LIBRARIES.html) variable exists, where you can append the libraries according to your need. However, this variable seemingly expect full path to the libraries.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34133996/2436175).