# Link a library as last against all targets

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm adding support for gperftools in my project to profile the cpu and memory. Gperftools needs the library tcmalloc to be linked **last** for each binary.

Is there a way with cmake to append a library to every binary targets of my project without having to edit each `CMakeLists.txt`?

I've found a similar question here: [link library to all targets in cmake project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819041/link-library-to-all-targets-in-cmake-project), but it does not answered. It is suggested to overcome the problem using macros, but it is not explained how this could be achieved.

Comment: You ask `Is there a way with cmake...` and the question you refers has a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819041/link-library-to-all-targets-in-cmake-project#comment49685024_30819041): `There is nothing builtin that removes this.`. It is just an answer to your question. Or do you prefer a formal answer(not a comment)?

Comment: It says there is nothing builtin but lets an open door to alternate ways such as a macro, I'm thinking in that way but have yet no idea how to do this properly.

Comment: I think you should first all collect a list of all existing targets. Unfortunately, this is yet another not built in capability of CMake https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-January/042079.html It seems though that you can override the standard `add_library` command https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-September/039388.html

Comment: Could you please add CMake code snippets of what you have tried so far and maybe what has worked already for a single target? One possibility would be - besides overwriting `add_executable()` - to modify/extend [`CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_LANG_LINK_EXECUTABLE.html), [`CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_LINK_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_LANG_IMPLICIT_LINK_LIBRARIES.html) or [`CMAKE_STANDARD_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_STANDARD_LIBRARIES.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Florian suggested, you can use [CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_STANDARD_LIBRARIES.html) variable for library which should be linked to every target as *system*, so it will be effectively **last** in link list.

There are a couple of things with this variable:

1. Unlike to what is written in CMake documentation, the variable's name contains `<LANG>` prefix.
2. While using this variable expects *full path* to the additional library, in case that additional library is not under *LD_LIBRARY_PATH*, executable will not work with `Cannot open shared object file error` error. For me, with `C` compiler (and corresponded prefix in the variable's name), `link_directories()` helps. With `C++`, only RPATH setting helps.

Example:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# Assume path to the additional library is <a-dir>/<a-filename>
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES <a-dir>/<a-filename>)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH <a-dir>)

add_executable(hello hello.cpp)
install(TARGETS hello DESTINATION bin)
```

**hello.cpp**:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    void p = malloc(10);
    if(p) free(p);
}
```

Assuming, e.g., that additional library replaces `malloc` function, executable will use that replacement.

Tested with CMake 2.8 and 3.4 on Linux (Makefile generator).

**Update**:

As suggested by @Falco, in case of `gcc` compiler additional library can be specified with `-l:` prefix:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES -l:<full-library-path>)
```

With such prefix `gcc` will link executable with given library using its full path, so the executable will work without additional RPATH settings.

Comment: This solution works and and fits my needs. You can improve it by using it this way: set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES -l:<a-dir>/<a-filename>)
The "-l:" makes gcc link to a full path lib, this avoids the need to have the lib in system path or adding it to LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I have added it to the post.