# CMake unable to link libxml2 in CLion

Tags: c++, cmake, libxml2, clion

**tl;dr add `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES "-lxml2" )` to `CMakeLists.txt` (more infos below).**

---

I want to run a very simple application within CLion. This application uses libxml2.

I use CLion 2018.1.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, `libxml2-dev` is properly installed.

My project does compile with:

```
g++ -I /usr/include/libxml2 xmlTest.cpp -o xmlTest.exe -lxml2
```

it does not compile in CLion though, using this `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(xmlTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -lz -lm")

include_directories( /usr/local/include/libxml2 )

add_executable (xmlTest.exe xmlTest.cpp)
```

the compiler throws me:

```
/home/xxxx/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/181.4668.70/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/xxxx/src/cmake-build-debug --target xmlTest.exe -- -I /usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2
Scanning dependencies of target xmlTest.exe
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xmlTest.exe.dir/xmlTest.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable xmlTest.exe
CMakeFiles/xmlTest.exe.dir/xmlTest.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/xxxx/src/xmlTest.cpp:10: undefined reference to `xmlReadFile'
/home/xxxx/src/xmlTest.cpp:17: undefined reference to `xmlDocGetRootElement'
/home/xxxx/src/xmlTest.cpp:21: undefined reference to `xmlFreeDoc'
/home/xxxx/src/xmlTest.cpp:25: undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
/home/xxxx/src/xmlTest.cpp:27: undefined reference to `xmlFreeDoc'
```

my application (`xmlTest.cpp`):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  xmlDocPtr doc;
  xmlNodePtr cur;

  doc = xmlReadFile(argv[1], NULL, 0);

  if (doc == NULL ) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Document not parsed successfully. \n");
    return 1;
  }

  cur = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

  if (cur == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"empty document\n");
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    return 1;
  }

  if (xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "users")) {
    fprintf(stderr,"document of the wrong type, root node != story");
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

after fiddling with libxml2 and CMake for hours now without success, I am open to any idea what to do to tell CMake `libxml2` actually exists...

---

**Update #1:**

thanks to @vre's suggestion I updated my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(xmlTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -lz -lm")
set(CMAKE_CXX "/usr/local/include/libxml2")
find_library(libxml2 libxml2)
link_directories(/usr/local/include/libxml2)
add_compile_options("-I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -lz -lm")
find_package(LibXml2 REQUIRED)
add_executable (xmlTest.exe xmlTest.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(xmlTest.exe PUBLIC ${LibXml2_DEFINITIONS})
target_include_directories(xmlTest.exe PUBLIC ${LibXml2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(xmlTest.exe ${LibXml2_LIBRARIES})
```

This did not change or resolve the error though.

**Update #2 (solution):**

this is how to build projects with `libxml2` in CLion:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(xmlTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -I/usr/include/libxml2")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES "-lxml2" )

add_executable (xmlTest.exe xmlTest.cpp)
```

My issue was that I had the wrong order of arguments in my `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc) points this out. Using `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES "-lxml2" )` was the key ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131414/link-a-library-as-last-against-all-targets))

I hope this helps some future timetravelers:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add "-l" (ell) compiler flag in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136418/how-to-add-l-ell-compiler-flag-in-cmake)

Comment: CFLAGS vs LDFLAGS

Comment: Thanks for the info's so far. Any concrete suggestion what I should add to my `CMakeLists.txt` as `target_link_libraries(<...>)` is not suitable here because I want to use a library not build it.

Comment: Technically this `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -lz -lm")` should add everything I need.

Comment: You don't need to build libxml2 by yourself to use `target_link_libaries`. I would use the modern CMake way and add `find_package(LibXml2 REQUIRED) add_executable(xmlTest.exe xmlTest.cpp) target_compile_definitions(xmlTest.exe ${LibXml2_DEFINITIONS}) target_include_directories(xmlTest.exe ${LibXml2_INCLUDE_DIRS}) target_link_libraries(xmlTest.exe ${LibXml2_LIBRARIES})` in that order to the `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @vre I added your suggestion, this does not resolve things though. (see the "Update".

Comment: Can you output the content of `${LibXml2_LIBRARIES}` with `message(STATUS "libmxl2 ${LibXml2_LIBRARIES}")`? And did you deleted the CMakeCache.txt file before doing the proposed changes?

Comment: The variable names have the wrong case, should be `LIBXML2_LIBRARIES`, `LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR`, respectively. `LIBXML2_DEFINITIONS` is empty.

Comment: Ah that's why. I mixed it up. So please use the variable names @Botje mentioned and  remove the entire call to `target_compile_definitions` It's  `LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIRS` btw. `LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR` is used to lookup libxml2 package.

Comment: thanks for all your help, I found the solution: `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES "-lxml2" )` . Updated my question for future time travelers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you came up with works but the intention of `CMake` is to provide means to express a platform, compiler, and build tool independent way of describing projects. All the magic happens in the `FindLibXml2.cmake` module. And a huge number of modules are delivered ready to use with your `CMake` installation. See the modules directory under `/usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules` on `Ubuntu 18.04`.

If you reformulate your `CMakeLists.txt` the following way:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(xmlTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")
elseif(MSVC)
  # add options for Visual C/C++ Compiler here
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /W4")
endif()    

find_package(LibXml2 REQUIRED)

add_executable(xmlTest.exe xmlTest.cpp)

target_compile_definitions(xmlTest.exe PUBLIC ${LIBXML2_DEFINITIONS})
target_include_directories(xmlTest.exe PUBLIC ${LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(xmlTest.exe ${LIBXML2_LIBRARIES})
```

you are able to work on a wide range of platforms and combinations of compilers and IDEs. This was tested on `Ubuntu 18.04` with `GCC 7.3` and `Windows 10` with `MSVC 15`. You need some more steps to build on Windows (i.e. installing and setup libxml2 and all of its dependencies). And this ***should*** work with `CLion` too out of the box.

Comment: Excellent, this also works and is the solution I use now. Thanks for clarifying what CMake is for. *I come from bare make files and just get into CMake.* Thanks!