# cmake: add library to all targets

Tags: cmake

Here is my workable CMakelists.txt.  The benchmark library is in  `/usr/local/lib/libbenchmark.a` and it is built with the standard process in [google benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(tiny_benchmark)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED on)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS off)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS on)
# set(CMAKE_STANDARD_LIBRARIES ${CMAKE_STANDARD_LIBRARIES}  pthread benchmark /usr/local/lib/benchmark.a)
# set(CMAKE_STANDARD_LIBRARIES ${CMAKE_STANDARD_LIBRARIES}  pthread)
add_executable(foo foo.cpp)
add_executable(bar bar.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo pthread benchmark)
target_link_libraries(bar pthread benchmark)
```

Since I have many small benchmark tool to build so I don't want call     `target_link_libraries(bar pthread benchmark)` for every library.

I want to just define the executable. and the pthread and benchmark can be added automatically.

I found `CMAKE_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` is designed for this purpose, but I tried
`CMAKE_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` and `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` in many format, but no one works.

What error did I make in this case? my CMake version is 3.5.1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use [link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/link_libraries.html) command. Its effect similar to `target_link_libraries`, but is applied to all targets created after the call.

```
link_libraries(pthread benchmark)

add_executable(foo foo.cpp)
add_executable(bar bar.cpp)
```