# CMake dependencies on a common static lib

Tags: cmake, dependencies, static-libraries

I have two separate projects, each builds a shared lib that links with a common static lib.
In each of the shared libs' CMakeLists.txt I'll have:

```
add_dependencies(my_shared1 my_common_lib)
```

and

```
add_dependencies(my_shared2 my_common_lib)
```

The static lib has its own sources and resides in its own folder. What is the best way to define the common static cmake script?

Comment: Shouldn't `add_dependencies` be replaced with `target_link_libraries`? (That would mean, that you `my_shared1` library not only *depends* on `my_common_lib` one, but is **linked** with it).

Comment: Could be! In any case the main point of my question remains...

Comment: If you mean `target_link_libraries`, then the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292879/cmake-add-library-to-all-targets (in short: use `link_libraries`).

Comment: I actually want to know how to cause target_link_libraries to invoke the building process for my_common_lib.

Comment: `target_link_libraries` implies target-level dependencies. That is, building of `my_shared1` library starts only after `my_common_lib` library will be built.

Comment: But what would be written in the `my_common_lib` script? If I write `add_library` and `include` it from the `my_shared` CMakeLists, then it would always attempt to build it?

Comment: Yes, it should work. What about just trying?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the included cmake would build `my_common_lib` in the same directory as the including cmake, resulting in two different builds of the common. And specifying the build directory for the common would also set it for the shared, since it is the same build unit... help!

Comment: Do shared libraries belongs to **different** projects? You have never said that before. If so, you need to build the project with `my_common_lib` as *standalone*. E.g., projects with shared libraries may use `ExternalProject_Add` for build the project with `my_common_lib`. If provide the same parameters to `ExternalProject_Add` in both project, common project will be built only once.

Comment: Correct, I've edited my Q to make it clear.
I've looked at ExternalProject_Add and it seems overwhelming. My initial thinking was to have something similar to Visual Studio (or Xcode) projects. The shared library would be a regular project, and the two others would also be regular projects and would specify the common one as a dependency. So, the common can build as a standalone if wanted, or, building any of the shared libs would invoke the build of the common.

Comment: @gil_mo How the projects are structured? Do they belong to the same source tree / repository? When building `my_shared*`, do you want that `my_common_lib` is built as well, or do you want it to find a pre-built and installed version of `my_common_lib`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your "projects" are *tightly* coupled (e.g. live in the same repository / have the same parent directory), just write a `CMakeLists.txt` above all three that calls [`add_subdirectory`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html) for each project's directory. If you use [`project`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html) in each, they should show up as separate entities in VS/XCode.

If not, just write your `CMakeLists.txt` for the static library like you normally would, have it export itself (check out [`export()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/export.html) and [`install(EXPORTS)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-exports)) and use [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) in the consumers to find it, then just `target_link_libraries` the imported target.

If these need to live in separate repositories, but you *also* need somewhere to create a build that builds all three, *then* you'll want to look at [External Projects](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html).

Comment: `add_subdirectory` is what I was looking for.